# Using Scanner.next() to split a String set into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to split a user inputed set, such as `{ 1 2 3 4 }`, as a string, into an array list so that when I print out the array list it will read `{1, 2, 3, 5}`. Here is my code so far. I am not really sure how the `Scanner.next()` method works, but I am attempting to use it. This is for a small portion of my program. Actually it's like the beginning.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class practice {
   public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
    String set;
    String set2 = "";

System.out.print("Enter set:");
set = stdIn.nextLine();
if(set.charAt(0) == '{'){
    for(int i =1; i<set.length(); i++){
        set2 += set.charAt(i);
    }
}
else if(set.charAt(1) == '{'){
    for(int i = 2; i <set.length();i++){
        set2 += set.charAt(i);
    }
}
System.out.print(set2);


ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(stdIn.next() != "}"){
    set2 = stdIn.next();
    array.add(Integer.parseInt(set2));
}
System.out.print(array);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `String.split(String)` and `String.replaceAll(String, String)` methods in `String` in order to do a lot of what your code currently does.

You can get the user input as you are currently doing it, with `stdIn.nextLine();`, but afterward, you can do the string processing in an easier way.

First, you should remove the unnecessary characters, and end up with just a sequence of numbers separated by spaces.

You can do this by simply calling the `replaceAll` method, and provide the regular expression, which is really simple in this case.

Then you can call the `String.split` method to find each element in the set.

```
String in = stdIn.nextLine();
// Need to escape the characters because
// these characters mean something special in regular expressions
String filtered = userInput.replaceAll("(\\[\\{\\}\\],"," ");
String[] numbers = filtered.split("\\s+");
ArrayList <Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList <Integer> ( numbers.length );
for ( String number : numbers )
    myNumbers.add ( Integer.parseInt ( number ) );
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to use a scanner, you can use a scanner for the String that has been filtered

```
Scanner s = new Scanner ( filtered );
ArrayList <Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
while ( s.hasNext() )
{
   myNumbers.add(s.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: apparently he has to use a scanner though.

Comment: Oh whoops! I must have not realized that. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use Java's [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method on a string.

**EDIT:**
If you are required to use scanner, you might want to start off something like:

```
String input = "foobar";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```

and then probably iterate on `s` using a while loop and the hasNext method. Inside this loop, you will possibly need to use one of the next methods in Java's [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) api to work with each token as string. If you only want to print things out, then you don't really need to add tokens to an arraylist. You can directly use `System.out.print()`. In any case, its well worth working this out on your own and exploring the scanner api.

Comment: Im supposed to use the Scanner.next() method

Comment: oh. is this homework? perhaps you might want to tag it as homework?

Comment: alright. they just kind of threw this Scanner.next() thing at us with no explanations so im trying to figure this whole thing out and its highly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten your while statement by taking in straight "ints" instead of actually passing then converting strings, like:

```
while (stdIn.next() != '}') {
    array.add(stdIn.nextInt());
}
```

However, you'd require some error handling to make sure you actually got ints just in case your user passed in something else. However, if you're wanting to print the integers as strings it may be better to use an String array instead of an Integer array.